# Network Manager wifi not available

Tags: networkmanager, wpa-supplicant

I have installed NetworkManager on my Arago linux machine. NetworkManager seems to bring up the ethernet interfaces fine, but the wifi interface is unavailable.

```
root@machine:~# nmcli d
DEVICE  TYPE      STATE        CONNECTION   
eth0    ethernet  connected    netplan-eth0 
eth1    ethernet  connected    netplan-eth1 
wlan0   wifi      unavailable  --
```

The issue seeems to be because NetworkManager can't acquire wpa_supplicant.

```
NetworkManager[251]: [0;1;39m<warn>  [1640291073.0649] supplicant: failed to acquire wpa_supplicant proxy: Wi-Fi and 802.1x will not be available (Error calling StartServiceByName for fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Er
ror.TimedOut: Failed to activate service 'fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms))
```

I'm not sure why it is failing to activate the dbus wpa_supplicant service.
I've added a wpa_supplicant.service which looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=WPA supplicant
Before=network.target
After=dbus.service
Wants=network.target
IgnoreOnIsolate=true

[Service]
Type=dbus
BusName=fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/wpa_supplicant -u -s -O /var/run/wpa_supplicant

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
Alias=dbus-fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1.service
```

And the fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1.service also exists in /usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/:

```
[D-BUS Service]
Name=fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1
Exec=/usr/sbin/wpa_supplicant -u -s -O /var/run/wpa_supplicant
User=root
SystemdService=wpa_supplicant.service
```

Any ideas on why this could be happening?
Thanks

Comment: At least here on Fedora there's a package `NetworkManager-wifi-1.32.12-2.fc35.x86_64` - maybe you need to install something similar in your distro which you've chosen not to specify.

Comment: My distro is Arago (updated the post). Thanks for the hint, I'll look into that.

Comment: If you restart the `wpa_supplicant` service, then restart `NetworkManager`, do you still get the same error?